# mv: No such file or directory error even though directory most certainly exists

Tags: shell, gentoo, mv

I am attempting to do the very simple task of moving `file.gz` from `/home/username/Downloads/file.gz` into `/mnt/gentoo/proc/`

When I issue `mv /home/username/Downloads/file.gz /mnt/gentoo/proc/` it returns with `mv: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/gentoo/proc/file.gz’: No such file or directory`

`ls /mnt/gentoo/proc` gives the huge list of files that are indeed in that directory. `ls /home/username/Downloads/` gives just `file.gz`

`touch /mnt/gentoo/proc/file.gz` didn't work and gave me `touch: cannot touch ‘/mnt/gentoo/proc/file.gz’: No such file or directory`

I can indeed move file.gz to other directories, but not into the one I want it in.

Output of `mount` is:

```
/cow on / type overlay (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdd on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=mint)
/dev/mapper/vg2-root on /mnt/gentoo type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg1-home on /mnt/gentoo/home type ext4 (rw)
none on /mnt/gentoo/proc type proc (rw)
/sys on /mnt/gentoo/sys type none (rw,bind)
/dev on /mnt/gentoo/dev type none (rw,bind)
```

Output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow                  3.9G  113M  3.8G   3% /
/dev                  3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /mnt/gentoo/dev
tmpfs                 794M  1.8M  792M   1% /run
/dev/sdd              1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0            1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
none                  4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                 3.9G  660K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  3.9G  1.5M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none                  100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg2-root  110G  4.7G  100G   5% /mnt/gentoo
/dev/mapper/vg1-home  917G   72M  870G   1% /mnt/gentoo/home
```

Comment: `/proc` is a special filesystem, it seems like you're trying to write on /proc filesystem mounted from another location or another system. Could you add the output of `mount` and `df -h`?

Comment: Yes I am, and they are unfortunately on different disks. File.gz is on /dev/sdd and the destination is on /dev/sdb. I should have included that on the original.

Comment: Are you trying to install gentoo?.  If not you need to shift the /proc on ubuntu by issuing `mount -t proc proc /mnt/gentoo/proc`  See [Entering the new environment](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Entering_the_new_environment). Sebastien is correct.

Comment: check the permissions on `/mnt/gentoo/proc/`  , it might be readonly

Comment: The root user has ownership over the proc folder and I am pretty sure it isn't read only. Output of `grep "\sro[\s,]" /proc/mounts` is `/dev/sdd /cdrom iso9660 ro,noatime 0 0
/dev/loop0 /rofs squashfs ro,noatime 0 0` Where /dev/sdd is the live USB, not what I'm writing to.

Comment: The kernel and the filesystem(s) are not lying to you. You are mistaken about something that you haven't shown properly.

Comment: This is what is known as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Please [edit] your question and explain why you want to copy something to /proc`. There is basically never a good reason to do so. Tell us what you are trying to achieve and we can give you an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) filesystem is a virtual filesystem (see also [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs))

In the output of the mount command it shows that `/mnt/gentoo/proc` is a filesystem of type `procfs`

```
none on /mnt/gentoo/proc type proc (rw)
```

This means that you can't create files in this location nor should you want to do so. Files inside a `procfs` are created by the system only. If you want to transfer a file from one disk to the other, just try copying it to a regular directory.

EDIT:
If what you really wanted to do is to build a kernel with a `config.gz` taken from another system, then you should have asked how to do that. It would be easier to get helpful responses if you describe what you want to achieve and possibly the solution is much simpler than you think.

Comment: I successfully copied the file into /mnt/gentoo but from there even with the chroot terminal I have in /mnt/gentoo, it gave the same error. `mv: cannot create regular file ‘proc/file.gz’: No such file or directory` I have a feeling I have misinterpreted your answer however.

Comment: @0x0, the simple answer is that you *can't* copy or create files in to `/mnt/gentoo/proc`. It is a special filesystem (procfs) that is used by the operating system for presenting system information. There's neither a valid reason for you to want to copy anything in there. If you want to transfer a file to another disk, you can try any other directory that isn't under a special filesystem, such as `procfs`, `sysfs`, `squashfs`, `devfs`, `tmpfs` or `none`.

Comment: I am attempting to compile the kernel and there isn't the config.gz in /proc like there is supposed to be. I have tried to reinstall the kernel sources package and upgrade system but it doesn't seem to work. I bet I could resolve this by using the official gentoo live USB rather than Mint.

Comment: @0x0, `/proc/config.gz` appears automatically if the `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` is enabled in the running kernel. It's probably disabled by default in Gentoo. You can't create this file yourself, but if all you want is to copy the config from another kernel build, you can copy the uncompressed version in your kernel source as `.config` and run `make oldconfig`. But better consult the gentoo guidelines for how to build kernels, there might be variations in the required steps (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Configuration).

Answer (score -2):

You try to create a file in a directory where you don't have the write permission: "cannot create regular file"

Change the permission you have on /mnt/gentoo/proc/

Comment: NO! You never change the permissions on system directories unless you have a very good reason to do so and know what you're doing. In any case, `/proc` is a special file system and the error received has nothing to do with permissions anyway.